# Python: ImportError happens on IDE suggestion

Tags: python, pycharm

**This is my packages structure:**

[image]

**This is my __init.py__ inside settings package:**

```
from settings import *
```

**This is my functions.py:**

```
from git import *
import initializer.settings as settings

_repo_remote = "https://%s:%s@%s" % (settings.git_username, settings.git_password, git_info["remote"])
```

Although I imported the settings package with my IDE auto-complete, I keep getting:

```
ImportError: No module named initializer.settings
```

When changing my import to:

```
import settings
```

The code works, but IDE is showing an error, why does it happen and what's wrong? I assume it is something with the path it try to load the module from, but I don't know how to change or control it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `main.py` is in the `'initializer'` folder (it appears to be?), you could import simply like this instead:

```
import settings
```

As long as the `__init__.py` in the `'settings'` folder is like you described it. You would need to have the `'main.py'` in the topmost folder to use it as you had it.